# AC circuit with unusually placed transformer

Tags: transformer

Here's the circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fukSIC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

$$I=2.25,0° mA$$
What's the $$n=N1/N2$$ of the transformer so that on R3 most power is dissipated. Power? U1?

What I don't know is what to do with the transformer. When it's in parallel I know. I just need help with that, else I think I would manage.

Comment: Like Russel McMahon said, it's an autotransformer, but your drawing obscures the fact.  A more conventional way to draw it would be as one coil with a tap in the middle, and a double bar that signifies the iron core.  https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Autotransformer.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What I don't know is what to do with the transformer. When it's in parallel I know. I just need help with that, else I think I would manage.

It's called an "auto transformer.
It obeys the usual rules for an ideal transformer

Call the voltage at the right hand end of R2 "Vin"

**Short:**

- Vin is divided between N1 & N2 in the ratio of their turns
  (as in any transformer) so -
- \$ Vout = \dfrac{N2}{N1+N2} \$

**Longer:**

$$ Vn2 = Vn1 \times N2/N1 \tag1 $$

So 
$$ Vn1 = Vn2 \times N1/N2 \tag2 $$

By inspection

$$ Vin = Vn1 + Vn2 \tag3 $$

So

$$ Vn1 = Vin - Vn2 ... \tag4 $$

From 2 & 4

$$ Vn2 \times N1/N2 = Vin - Vn2 $$
$$ Vn2 \times (N1/N2 +1 ) = Vin $$
$$ Vn2 = \dfrac{Vin}{N1/N2 + 1} $$ 
$$ Vn2 = \dfrac{Vin}{(N1 + N2) / N2} $$
$$ Vn2 = \dfrac{Vin \times N2}{N1 + N2} $$

i.e., MUCH more simply,
Vin is divided across N1 and N2 in the ratio of their turns.

**Example**

If N1:N2 = 1:9 Vout is 90% of Vin.
If N1:N2 = 9:1 Vout is 10% of Vin.

---

[Wikipedia - autotransformer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autotransformer)

[Autotransformer basics](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transformer/auto-transformer.html)

[Autotransformers](http://www.vias.org/matsch_capmag/matsch_caps_magnetics_chap6_09.html)

[Many examples](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=autotransformer&biw=1396&bih=877&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=ZPuDVYbJGYXs8AW_q5bQAw&sqi=2&ved=0CEMQsAQ)